# How to target last child of specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to target the last child of the active class either with jQuery or CSS I used the last-of-type pseudo class but it didn't work

HTML CODE

```
<div class="owl-item cloned">Element</div>
<div class="owl-item cloned">Element</div>
<div class="owl-item cloned">Element</div>
<div class="owl-item active">Element</div>
<div class="owl-item active">Element</div>
<div class="owl-item active">This What I want to target</div>
<div class="owl-item cloned">Element</div>
<div class="owl-item cloned">Element</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
.owl-item {
    background-color: green;
    color:#FFF;
    margin: 10px 50px;
    padding: 10px
}
.owl-item.active:last-of-type {
    background-color: red;
}
```

This is a live demo [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vx4uzLbp/)

Comment: `<div class="owl-item active">This What I want to target</div>` is not a last child

Comment: @NoDownvotesPlz It is the last child of active class

Comment: It's *well worth your time* to read through the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It  only takes an hour or two, and repays you that much time within days at most.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I still learn jQuery but this was an emergency so I can't wait till I finish the documentation. Thank you

Comment: So many of these questions, did you even try searching for this?

Comment: @Pete If you compare the two topics you'll find that mine is not duplicated please consider next time comparing posts then you can judge.

Comment: Are you not wanting to select the last child with a particular class? A quick search brings up lots of options - all js based, perhaps you should try researching a little harder before posting next time.  read the top few paragraphs: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery:

```
jQuery('.owl-item.active').last().css('background-color', 'blue')
```

EDIT:

The `.css('background-color', 'blue')` part is only an example.
`jQuery('.owl-item.active').last()` gets the last Element.

Comment: `jQuery('.owl-item.active:last')`

Comment: This is what I want, I will accepted as the answer as soon as I will be able to do that (After 10 min). Thank you

Comment: @Jai: See the "additional notes" on the [`:last` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) for why `.last()` may be preferred.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I absolutely confirm that. http://jsperf.com/jquery-last-selector-vs-last-method